# Creating more than 3 connections in Office 365 Exchange via powershell.

Tags: powershell-3.0, office365

I get the following error when i try to connect to Office365 exchange:

"Fail to create a runspace because you have exceeded the maximum number of connections allowed : 3 for the policy party : MaxConcurrency. Please close existing runspace and try again."

Is there any way in which i run more than 3 sessions concurrenlty from one account.

Regards,

Vineet

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same error before. According to [msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984289%28v=exchg.150%29):

Be sure to disconnect the remote PowerShell session when you're finished. If you close the Windows PowerShell window without disconnecting the session, you could use up all the remote PowerShell sessions available to you, and you'll need to wait for the sessions to expire. To disconnect the remote PowerShell session, run the following command.

```
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

I think it is because that the powershell script creates the remote runspace on the exchange online server, as the resource of the service is limited, so Microsoft puts a limit of 3 remote runspaces for each user. However, there's no document explain why the limit is 3, and how can we increase it. I also looked into the exchange online portal, there's no such setting.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the amount of connections you have to open a support ticket to Microsoft. They can increase your number of connections based off the number of users in your tenant. Open a case with the Exchange Online team, with the title "Increase Throttle Policy".

Answer (score 1):

As Matt above said but only the following command worked for me

Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession